# Modify MDI child control from parent and vise-versa

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, controls, mdi

I have a dynamically created chart in my child form that I wish to modify from parent.

How do I modify a dynamically created control on child from parent and vise-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a method in the child form (or better yet, its base class if you are using inheritance) that the parent can call.  In the Parent form, use `ActiveMDIChild` to get a reference to the form, cast to the child's class, and call it.

Once you are in the method, you can act on the (local) control.

Comment: I need to be able to change it even if the child doesn't have focus.

Comment: If it doesn't have focus, and there are 3 forms open, how will you determine which form's control(s) to act upon?

Comment: There will only be one with a chart, though.

Comment: Not very forward-thinking, but if you want to make that assumption, then loop through `MdiChildren`, subsequently looping through each childs `Controls`, until you find the one that has it, then call the method.